# Node application not woriking with ngrok

Tags: node.js, ngrok

I have node application that works fine on my localhost, but whenever I try to access it with NGROK from another devcie it shows only the home page but node app does not work, please help me solve this problem,

any help is apreciated.

best reagrds...

Comment: Your question is extremely vague. Can you please provide more details about the app and the code you you're working with?

Answer (score 0):

Honestly never used Ngrok, but I use http://localtunnel.me/ looks like it does the same, if is not working with this then you should probably share some code to see what is going on